# Java NumberFormatException when check

Tags: java

Sorry, if this have a simple solution, but I can't figure it out.

I have problem with NumberFormatException(Error):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

I have button, and when its pressed, it cheks different things, but it don't like one line in code.

Line: `if(Integer.parseInt(CarsLv1.cars[j]) == 0){`

I tried to make this line different, but it still makes same error:

```
if(j == 3){
```

Carslv1.cars = String Array.
All other like CarMain = Integer Arrays.

Full Code, if Button clicked:

```
if(ae.getSource() == jbtnBuildCarLv1){
    if(CarMain.main[5] >=1){
        if(CarMain.main[7] >0){
            if(CarFrame.frames[1] >0){ 

                for(int i=1;i <= 25;i+=2){
                    if(Part.parts[i] >0){
                        count0+=1;

                    }
                    else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You don't have enought parts!", "No Parts", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.NoPartsIcon);}                            
                }

            if (count0 == 13){              
                for (int j = 3;j <= 80; j+= 4){
                    if(Integer.parseInt(CarsLv1.cars[j]) == 0){                 
                        for(int i=1;i <= 25;i+=2){
                            Part.parts[i] --;

                            int count = Integer.parseInt(CarsLv1.cars[j]); count+=1; 
                            CarsLv1.cars[j] = Integer.toString(count);

                            if(j == 3){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Aston Martin DB9!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Aston_Martin_DB9Icon);
                            }
                            if(j == 7){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Acura NSX!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Acura_NSXIcon);
                            }
                            if(j == 11){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Ford Mustang!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Ford_MustangIcon);
                            }
                            if(j == 15){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Moskvich 412!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Moskvich_412Icon);
                            }
                            if(j == 19){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Kia Venga!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Kia_VengaIcon);
                            }
                            if(j == 23){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Fiat 1500!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Fiat_1500Icon);
                            }
                            if(j == 27){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Ferrari Enzo!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Ferrari_EnzoIcon);
                            }
                            if(j == 31){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Aston Martin Rapide!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Aston_Martin_RapideIcon);
                            }
                            if(j == 35){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Koenigsegg CCX!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Koenigsegg_CCXIcon);
                            }
                            if(j == 39){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Honda Civic!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Honda_CivicIcon);
                            }
                            if(j == 43){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Cadilliac ATS!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Cadilliac_ATSIcon);
                            }
                            if(j == 47){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Mitsubishi Lancer Evolution X!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,ImagesHolder.Mitsubishi_LancerEvolutionXIcon);
                            }
                            if(j == 51){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Infiniti FX!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Infiniti_FXIcon);
                            }
                            if(j == 55){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Lancia Thema!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Lancia_ThemaIcon);
                            }
                            if(j == 59){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Volvo XC90!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Volvo_XC90Icon);
                            }
                            if(j == 63){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Acura CSX!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Acura_CSXIcon);
                            }
                            if(j == 67){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Saab Sonett II!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Saab_SonettIIIcon);
                            }
                            if(j == 71){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Renault Floride!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Renault_FlorideIcon);
                            }
                            if(j == 75){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained BMW e34!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.BMW_e34Icon);
                            }
                            if(j == 79){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Chrysler Cordoba!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Chrysler_CordobaIcon);
                            }
                            else{
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have colected all 1 LVL cars", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.MaxUpgradeIcon);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You don't have 1 LVL car frame!", "No Car Frame", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.NoFrameIcon);}
            }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You don't have available garage slot!", "No Garage Slot", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.NoGarageIcon);
        }
        }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You don't have enought player level!", "No Player Level", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.NoPlayerIcon);
    }  
}
```

CarsLv1Class(Array) Code:

```
package Clicker;

public class CarLevel1Holder {


    public String cars[] = new String[80];

    public CarLevel1Holder(){


    }

    public void CarsMaker(String a1,int k, String a2,int k1, String a3,int k2,String a4,int k3){

        cars[k] = a1;
        cars[k1] = a2;
        cars[k2] = a3;
        cars[k3] = a4;

    }

    public void MakeCars(){

        int u = 0;int i = 1;int o = 2;int p = 3;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"Aston_Martin", i,"British",o, "0", p);   //Aston_Martin_DB9
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+= 4;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"Acura", i,"Japanese",o, "0",p);          //Acura_NSX
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+= 4;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"Ford", i,"American", o,"0",p);           //Ford_Mustang
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+= 4;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"Moskvich", i,"Russian", o,"0",p);        //Moskvich_412
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+= 4;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"Kia", i,"Korean",o,"0",p);               //Kia_Venga
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+= 4;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"Fiat", i,"Italian", o,"0",p);            //Fiat_1500
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+= 4;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"Ferrari", i,"Italian", o,"0",p);         //Ferrari_Enzo
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+= 4;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"Aston_Martin", i,"British", o,"0",p);    //Aston_Martin_Rapide
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+= 4;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"Koenigsegg", i,"Swedish", o,"0",p);      //Koenigsegg_CCX
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+= 4;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"Honda", i,"Japanese", o,"0",p);          //Honda_Civic
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+= 4;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"Cadilliac", i,"American", o,"0",p);      //Cadilliac_ATS
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+= 4;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"Mitsubishi", i,"Japanese", o,"0",p);     //Mitsubishi_LancerEvolutionX
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+= 4;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"Infiniti", i,"Japanese", o,"0",p);       //Infiniti_FX
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+= 4;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"Lancia", i,"Italian", o,"0",p);          //Lancia_Thema
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+= 4;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"Volvo", i,"Swedish", o,"0",p);           //Volvo_XC90
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+= 4;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"Acura", i,"Japanese", o,"0",p);          //Acura_CSX
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+= 4;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"Saab", i,"Swedish", o,"0",p);            //Saab_SonettII
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+= 4;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"Renault", i,"French", o,"0",p);          //Renault_Floride
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+= 4;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"BMW", i,"Germany", o,"0",p);             //BMW_e34
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+= 4;
        CarsMaker("Type", u,"Chrysler", i,"American", o,"0",p);       //Chrysler_Cordoba
         u += 4; i += 4; o +=4; p+=4;




//      CarsLv1 Aston_Martin_DB9 = new CarsLv1("Type", "Aston_Martin", "British", 0);       
//      CarsLv1 Acura_NSX = new CarsLv1("Type", "Acura", "Japanese", 0);
//      CarsLv1 Ford_Mustang = new CarsLv1("Type", "Ford", "American", 0);
//      CarsLv1 Moskvich_412 = new CarsLv1("Type", "Moskvich", "Russian", 0);
//      CarsLv1 Kia_Venga = new CarsLv1("Type", "Kia", "Korean", 0);
//      CarsLv1 Fiat_1500 = new CarsLv1("Type", "Fiat", "Italian", 0);
//      CarsLv1 Ferrari_Enzo = new CarsLv1("Type", "Ferrari", "Italian", 0);
//      CarsLv1 Aston_Martin_Rapide = new CarsLv1("Type", "Aston_Martin", "British", 0);
//      CarsLv1 Koenigsegg_CCX = new CarsLv1("Type", "Koenigsegg", "Swedish", 0);
//      CarsLv1 Honda_Civic = new CarsLv1("Type", "Honda", "Japanese", 0);
//      CarsLv1 Cadilliac_ATS = new CarsLv1("Type", "Cadilliac", "American", 0);
//      CarsLv1 Mitsubishi_LancerEvolutionX = new CarsLv1("Type", "Mitsubishi", "Japanese", 0);
//      CarsLv1 Infiniti_FX = new CarsLv1("Type", "Infiniti", "Japanese", 0);
//      CarsLv1 Lancia_Thema = new CarsLv1("Type", "Lancia", "Italian", 0);
//      CarsLv1 Volvo_XC90 = new CarsLv1("Type", "Volvo", "Swedish",  0);
//      CarsLv1 Acura_CSX = new CarsLv1("Type", "Acura", "Japanese", 0);
//      CarsLv1 Saab_SonettII = new CarsLv1("Type", "Saab", "Swedish", 0);
//      CarsLv1 Renault_Floride = new CarsLv1("Type", "Renault", "French", 0);
//      CarsLv1 BMW_e34 = new CarsLv1("Type", "BMW", "Germany", 0);
//      CarsLv1 Chrysler_Cordoba = new CarsLv1("Type", "Chrysler", "American", 0);


    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you call `System.out.println(CarsLv1.cars[j])` right before that line, to see what string returns that error

Comment: Is it possible that there's a value of `j` for which `CarsLv1.cars[j]` is null?

Comment: @DavidWallace not just possible, there's definitely an occurrence of this

Comment: Based on the exception, `CarsLvl.cars[j]` is clearly null.  The answer in this case is to do some debugging.  You're making a wrong assumption about your array somewhere...

Comment: And avoid deeply nested if statements. And learn about `else`. And learn about `switch` statements.

Comment: @Brian Why this error is just for String Array? For Integer Arrays all work. I edited post with CarsLv1 class. And how j can be null if i define j, just before that line in loop? "for (int j = 3;j <= 80; j+= 4)"

Comment: @crelix, like I said -- you need to debug your code.  Which loop iteration does it fail on?  The first?  The 10th?  The last?  Why isn't it working?  These are questions I can't answer because I don't have all the code (and even if I did, I'm not going to debug it for you -- I only have energy to say "Well, this part looks funny.  Pay attention to that.").

Comment: @Brain ,I did debugging, line where, problem is "if(Integer.parseInt(CarsLv1.cars[j]) == 0){" Before that, all works.

Comment: @crelix Let me ask my question another way.  What do you want to happen in the case where `CarsLv1.cars[j]` is null?  And why haven't you included code to either process that case, or to make that case impossible?

Comment: @DavidWallace I don't want it to be null. I want that CarsLv1.cars[j] is like CarsLv1.cars[3] , CarsLv1.cars[7], till [80]. So it can give +1 to Array value. If CarsLv1.cars[3] value 0, then this makes CarsLv1.Cars[3] value to 1. If I understood you right. (Sorry, I got bad English(Not my Native language))

Comment: OK, but it IS null, so THAT's what you need to fix.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yeah, and I'm trying, but can't understand how to fix it. But if i make (j == 3), and before that i set (int j = 3) why, it makes same error? (Sorry, maybe, I'm so stupid, to understand this...)

Comment: Maybe because you're doing `Integer.parseInt(CarsLv1.cars[j])` again four lines further down in the code?

Comment: Like here? "int count = Integer.parseInt(CarsLv1.cars[j]); count+=1; " If I understood right. I deleted it, and still nothing it shows. That line, where Integer.parseInt(CarsLv1.cars[j]) == 0 // Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at Clicker.ClickerGame.actionPerformed(ClickerGame.java:5293)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if(Integer.parseInt(CarsLv1.cars[j]) == 0){`

You should read this like

`if(Integer.parseInt(null) == 0){`

because CarLv1.cars[j] is null in this case. You need to fix this. And you may want to use a debugger and step through so you can capture the exact value of j

Answer (score 0):

Just catch the number format exception ?

```
try{
    int count = Integer.parseInt(CarsLv1.cars[j]);
    if(count == 0){
        for(int i=1;i <= 25;i+=2){ 
            ...
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e){}
```